# Does Twilio require special configuration when running behind an https server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, twilio, sms, nodemailer

I've integrated the basic Twilio SMS functionality for NodeJS ( `v16.13.1` ) on my local machine ( `http` ) and have seen everything working fine. But once it's deployed onto may staging server ( `https` ) I'm seeing this error:

```
[Error: 140251391358848:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ssl3_get_record',
  reason: 'wrong version number',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

All other ssl connections work fine, a quick curl check from the server works well also

`curl https://api.twilio.com/ -v`

Twilio Implementation:

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');

    this.twilioClient = new Twilio(accountSID, authToken);
    this.twilioClient.messages
        .create({
            body: textBody,
            to: recipientPhone,
            from: this.twilioConfig.sendingNumber
        })
        .then((message) => logger.log(`SMS Sent: messageId: ${message.sid}`))
        .catch((err) => logger.log(`Error sending SMS: ${err}`))
```

- NodeJS v16.13.1
- Twilio ^3.80.0

Apache SSLProtocol configurations I've tried:

```
#  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
#  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
  SSLProtocol all +TLSv1.2
```

I can't seem to find the root cause of this error. Twilio is saying they only support TLSv1.2, so I've specifically enabled that, but no dice ( and yes I restart apache each time ).

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Are you running a proxy between your application and Twilio at all? Your Apache config is for your web server receiving connections, but this is your server making a  connection, so that's what we need to look into?

Comment: @philnash good distinction on the Apache configuration. No proxy that I've set up; I make other outgoing https calls from the server that all work fine. Npm has both `proxy` and `https-proxy` fields as null in config. Is there a way to test if my app is behind a proxy?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit lost with this. Twilio is working, because you can call from your local machine. There must be something up with your server, but I don't think I can help, sorry.

Comment: @philnash yep, turns out not to be Twilio's fault, but an email config change ( which happens immediately before the Twilio call ) but I missed it. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it was an incorrect Nodemailer email config, which was being called immediately before Twilio in my case. Since Twilio was the new piece of code it unfortunately got the blame.

So for anyone who finds this later, Twilio did not cause this issue; but having a config for Nodemailer like this, for example:

```
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
    },
  });
```

This line here is the important part:

> secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports

If you have this wrong, it will throw the `wrong version number` ssl error.

(ref: https://nodemailer.com/about/ )

Comment: Glad you discovered this and thanks for sharing the update!